# Is $\tan (\pi x)$ never rational for all rational $x$ in the interval $(-0.5,0.5)$, with the exceptions occuring at $x=0, -0.25, 0.25$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request

What I'm claiming is that I have devised a proof of this statement which says that it is true. The proof is a little long and involves trigonometry and basics of number theory, so I feel lazy to include it here. I want to know whether such a result exists or not from before. If there exists one, then please refer me to the very website(s) containing the existing proofs.

I've used the identity,
(1+x2)n = (nC0 – nC2x2 + nC4x4 - ...)2 + (nC1x – nC3x3 + nC5x5 - …)2
to show that tan(pπ/q) with p≠0 and odd q is never rational.

Next, I've analyzed the zeroes of the polynomial
(nC0 – nC2x2 + nC4x4 - ...)
to show that tan (pπ/q) with odd p and even q is never rational except for (p/q)=±0.25.

...and still sorry for being lazy.

Comment: I bet you, lazy guys would not get help here!

Comment: To the serial downvoters: notice that this question clearly is a *reference request* (although the OP didn't tag it as such), so there's no problem with the OP being lazy.

Comment: To Shobhit, Babak S. and Michael Albanese (who where the people involved [this edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/452679/5)). Can any of you explain to me the comma after *then* in `If there exists one then, please refer...`?

Comment: Granted, monsieur, you have proved the statement. Some one else might have proved this in a different way than what you have done. Only if you show us your proof can we check whether it has already been done!

Comment: It is well-known exactly which rational $x$ result in rational values of $\tan\pi x$, $\sin\pi x$, and so on. You can probably find the details in Niven's book on irrational numbers.

Comment: Essentially answered at this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79861/arctan2-a-rational-multiple-of-pi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's proved at http://www.oberlin.edu/faculty/jcalcut/tanpap.pdf (J. S. Calcut, Rationality and the tangent function).