# Are there numbers $x, y \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $\tan(x) + \tan(y) \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: number-theory, trigonometry, rationality-testing

My question is related to the following one: [Is $\{\tan(x) : x\in \mathbb{Q}\}$ a group under addition?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/533171/279515)

It was shown that the above set is not closed under addition using the [Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem). That tells us that $\tan(x) + \tan(y)$ need not be of the form $\tan(z)$ where $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Q}$.

An initial attempt in trying to show that the above set is not closed involved trying to find $x, y \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $\tan(x) + \tan(y) \in \mathbb{Q}$, because $\tan(x)$ is irrational when $x$ is a non-zero rational. However, I have not managed to find any rational numbers that do satisfy this property. I'm looking for non-trivial examples, so I'm discounting the case $x=-y$ for which $\tan(x) + \tan(y) = 0$.

The primary difficulty that I faced was that the decimal expansion gave me no clues whether I was looking at a rational number or an irrational number. I also tried playing with the formula for $\tan(x+y)$ but I was not able to derive anything from that either. I checked a few of my guesses on Wolfram|Alpha and it says that they are all transcendental.

I'm beginning to suspect that $\tan(x) + \tan(y)$ is never rational when $x$ and $y$ are rational, but I don't know how to prove that either. Does anyone have any ideas on the best way to proceed? Thank you for your help.

Comment: $x=y=0$ then $\tan x+\tan y$ is rational

Comment: "Discounting $x = -y$"

Comment: In other words, you're asking if $\{\tan x+\tan y\mid x,y\in\Bbb Q\}\cap\Bbb Q$ equals the empty set.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Yes, that's a neater way to put it. I want to know if it's not the set $\{ 0 \}$.

Comment: The answer would be no if it is known that tan x must be transcendental for $x \neq 0$ rational. Is that known?

Comment: @Aravind It is known that $\tan(x)$ is transcendental when $x$ is a non-zero algebraic number. This result is stated in Niven's monograph _Irrational Numbers_ as an application of the Generalized Lindemann Theorem.

Comment: @Aravind Could you clarify how the answer would then be known?

Comment: Let $x=\dfrac{p}{q}$ and $y=\dfrac{r}{s}$ and let $z= tan \dfrac{1}{qs}$. Then it appears that tan x+tan y $\in \mathbb{Q}$ yields a polynomial equation for $z$.

Comment: @Aravind That looks like a legitimate solution to me! You should write that up as an answer.  (Short version: by induction, $\tan(nz)$ is a rational function of $\tan(z)$ for all $n$; therefore, $\tan(p/q)$ and $\tan(r/s)$ are rational functions of $\tan(1/qs)$, etc etc.)

Comment: I don't understand how that works. If I have a rational function of an irrational, would that be rational?

Comment: @BrahadeeshS. if Aravind hasn't written up his argument by tomorrow morning I'll give it a quick writeup to make things clear.  (It's not just 'irrational' but 'transcendental' that's essential here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=\dfrac{p}{q}$ and $y=\dfrac{r}{s}$ and $z=\dfrac{1}{qs}$.

We observe that tan x and tan y are polynomials in tan z; further tan x + tan y is a non-constant polynomial if $x+y \neq 0$. Here some calculation should show that tan $A\theta$ + tan $B\theta$ is a non-constant polynomial for $A + B \neq 0$.

Hence we have:if tan x + tan y is rational, then tan z is the root of a polynomial with rational coefficients, contradicting the Generalized Linedmann Theorem, as pointed out by the OP.

Comment: Wouldn't $\tan(x)$ and $\tan(y)$ would be ratios of polynomials in $tan(z)$?