# $\arctan$ of a square root as a rational multiple of $\pi$

Tags: trigonometry, algebraic-number-theory, irrational-numbers, rational-functions

I know that if $x$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$, then $\tan(x)$ is [algebraic](http://divisbyzero.com/2010/10/28/trigonometric-functions-and-rational-multiples-of-pi/).

Is there a fairly simple way to express $x$ as $\pi\frac{m}{n}$, if $\tan(x)$ is given as a square root of a rational?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is NO in general : the converse of your statement does not hold. For example, if $\tan(x)=\sqrt{2}$ then $2\cos(x)=\pm\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$ which is algebraic but not an algebraic integer, so $x$ cannot be a rational multiple of $\pi$ (see the first answer to that related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79861/arctan2-a-rational-multiple-of-pi?rq=1) for example).

If $\tan(x)=\sqrt{\frac{p}{q}}$ where $p$ and $q$ are coprime positive integers, you will have $2\cos(x)=\pm \sqrt{\frac{4q}{p+q}}$, and this will be an algebraic integer iff $p+q$ divides $4q$, iff $p+q$ divides $4$ (since $p+q$ is coprime to $q$), iff $p+q$ is one of $1,2$ or $4$, iff $(p,q)$ is one of $(1,1),(1,3)$ or $(3,1)$.

Comment: $2\cos(x)$ is an algebraic integer.  Consider $\arctan \sqrt{3}$ for example.

Comment: @WimC corrected, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The complete theory analogous to the one for rational tangents is worked out in

> On Angles Whose Squared Trigonometric Functions are Rational
>    by John H. Conway, Charles Radin, Lorenzo Sadun
>    http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/9812019