# $ \arctan \sqrt 2 $ is not a rational multiple of $\pi $

Tags: number-theory, trigonometry

How to show that $ \arctan \sqrt 2 \not =q\pi$ for $q\in \mathbb Q $  ?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579031/arctan-of-a-square-root-as-a-rational-multiple-of-pi

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79861/arctan2-a-rational-multiple-of-pi