# Show that $\arctan(n)$ is irrational for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, irrational-numbers

**Question** : Show that $\arctan(n)$ is irrational for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

**Hint:**

My solution doesn't use continued fraction.

> I am interested in other possible proofs for this question.

Comment: I proved that $\arctan(q)$ is not a rational multiple of $\pi$ for any rational $q\neq \pm 1,0$ here. http://math.stackexchange.com/a/79867/7933 I realize, that doesn't eactly help...

Comment: "other possible proofs"---Other than what?

Comment: Thomas Andrews, I didn't know about this. It's very interesting. Thank you.

Comment: Jonas Meyer. I'm being cryptic, I'm waiting for solutions.

Comment: Do you mean $n$ radians or $n$ degrees?

Comment: @lhf: No.${}{}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose that $\arctan n=r\in\Bbb Q$, where $n$ is a non-zero integer.  Then $r$ is not zero, so $2r$ is not zero, and
$$\cos2r=\frac{\cos^2r-\sin^2r}{\cos^2r+\sin^2r}
  =\frac{1-\tan^2r}{1+\tan^2r}=\frac{1-n^2}{1+n^2}$$
which is rational.  But this contradicts the result that the cosine of a non-zero rational number is irrational.

---

As for the proof of this result, it is usually done by taking an integral such as
$$\int_0^r f(x)\sin x\,dx\ ,$$
where $f(x)=x^n(a-bx)^{2n}(2a-bx)^n$ and $r=a/b$, and showing that if $n$ is large we get contradictory estimates for the integral.  See, for example, [my lecture notes,](http://www.maths.unsw.edu.au/~angell/5535/chapter2.ps) starting at page 20.

Comment: My solution is equal to what you did: I suppose $arctg(n)$ is rational, so $2arctg(n) = c = \frac{a}{b} \in \Bbb Q$ . So, $tg(\frac{c}{2})=n$.
Define $f(x) = x^n \frac{(a-bx)^n}{n!}$. Take $\int_0^{\frac{a}{b}} f(x)\sin x dx = F'(a/b)sin(a/b) +F(0)(1- cos(a/b)) > 0$, where $F(0)$ and $F'(a/b)$ are integers.  But $\frac{(1-cos(x))}{sen(x)}=tg(\frac{x}{2})$.
So, 
$F'(a/b) +F(0)tg(\frac{a}{2b})  =  F'(a/b) +F(0)tg(\frac{c}{2}) > 0$ ...

Comment: By an identical proof: $\arctan \frac 1n$ is irrational for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.