# Exact value of $\arctan(2)$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

The following problem has been on my mind for a while.

Lots of exact values of the arctangent function are known, such as
$$\arctan 0=0$$
$$\arctan 1=\frac{\pi}{4}$$
$$\arctan \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}=\frac{\pi}{6}$$
However, I can't seem to find an exact value of
$$\arctan 2$$
How can I find one? Is it possible?

**NOTE:** By exact, I mean that I am looking for an answer in the form
$$\frac{p\pi}{q}$$
with $p,q\in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Looking at the continued fraction of $\frac{\arctan(2)}{\pi}$, I would guess that it is not possible. Proving it is something else. I would even guess that it is transcendental.

Comment: I don't think it is a rational multiple of $\pi$ at all.

Comment: @Peter Any ideas about how I might show this?

Comment: @Nilknarf No, irrationality proofs are usually very difficult. For instance, we do not know whether $e+\pi$ is rational.

Comment: @Peter Does it help that it is also equal to $\arccos \frac{1}{\sqrt 5}$ or $\arcsin \frac{2}{\sqrt 5}$?

Comment: $p$ and $q$ must be very large (if there actually is a representation)

Comment: @Peter Ah. Did you use mathematica or some other math software to find that out?

Comment: @Nilknarf :P Any decent calculator approximation of $\arctan(2)/\pi$ does the trick

Comment: I used PARI/GP with very high precision ($10^5$ digits) and the continued fraction still does not terminate early or produce extremely large entries. This shows that there is no "small" solution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

$\arctan 2$ is not a rational multiple of $\pi$.  If it were, then for some integer $n > 0$, we would have $(1 + 2i)^n$ is real.  On the other hand, if we define $a_n := \operatorname{Im}((1 + 2i)^n)$, it is straightforward to show that this sequence satisfies the recurrence relation:
$$a_{n+2} = 2 a_{n+1} - 5 a_n, \, n \ge 0.$$
But now $a_0 = 0$ and $a_1 = 2$, so by induction, it is straightforward to show $a_n \equiv 2^{n+1} \pmod{5}$ for $n \ge 1$.  Since no power of 2 is divisible by 5, this implies that $a_n \ne 0$ for $n \ge 1$.

Comment: How does "$(1+2i)^n$ is real" follow from "$\arctan 2$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$"?

Comment: @Nilknarf $$1+2i=\sqrt5e^{i\arctan(2)}$$

Comment: $1+2i = \sqrt{5} e^{i \arctan(2)}$.

Comment: Ingenious solution! (+1)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Is this actually a valid proof ? If yes, then I am really impressed!

Comment: @Peter Why indeed, the induction step is also quite obvious, and everything seems to check out.

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/79867/7933

Answer (score 9):

If $\arctan(2)$ were a rational multiple of $\pi$, then $\alpha=\frac{1+2i}{\sqrt{5}}$ would be a $m$-th root of unity for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$. On the other hand the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $x^4+\frac{6}{5}x^2+1$, and this is not a [cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial), since cyclotomic polynomials always have integer coefficients (by Moebius inversion formula, if you like). It follows that $\alpha$ is not a $m$-th root of unity and

$$ \frac{\arctan 2}{\pi}\color{red}{\not\in}\mathbb{Q}.$$

Small variation: there are not so many cyclotomic polynomials with degree $4$. As many as the solutions of $\varphi(n)=4$, given by $n\in\{8,10,12\}$. The minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ does not belong to the set $\{\Phi_8(x),\Phi_{10}(x),\Phi_{12}(x)\}$ and the conclusion is the same.

---

Anyway, by the [Shafer-Fink inequality](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.0753) a pretty good approximation of $\arctan 2$ is provided by
$$ \frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{3/2}{1+2\sqrt{1+1/4}}=\color{blue}{\frac{1}{8} \left(3-3 \sqrt{5}+4 \pi \right)}.$$

Comment: >.< Darned, you're late on this one.

Comment: More general solution than mine, +1.  (In this case, you could also observe that the minimal polynomial implies $\alpha$ is not integral over $\mathbb{Z}$, while any $m$th root of unity is of course integral.)

Comment: Lol, how many PDF's of your do I not know about?