# How to find the shaded area

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, area, quadrilateral

How to find the shaded area crossed by semi-circle of radius 2 and quarter-circle of radius 4?
[image]

Comment: I have 2 arctan(2)*4*pi - 8/5 + 2 arctan(1/2)*16*pi - 32/5. However arctan(2) and arctan(1/2) are not rational multiple of pi. And this question is supposed to be an elementary school math question, so the answer should be in terms of pi, without trigonometry.

Answer (score 6):

The shaded area is shaped from two intersecting circles like an asymmetric lens! in order to find the area of this lens we simply split it in two parts:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! What software do you use to draw such nice diagrams?

Comment: @EdZeng, I use C.a.r which is for free. Here is it's address:http://car.rene-grothmann.de/doc_en/download.html

Answer (score 5):

Hint.

[image]

(This space intentionally left blank.)

---

**Solution.**

[image]

$$\begin{align}
\frac12\cdot\text{target area} &= A + B \\
&= \left( \frac12 \cdot (2s)^2\cdot\alpha - 4 C\right) + \left(\frac12 \cdot s^2 \cdot \beta - C \right) \\[4pt]
&= \frac12 s^2\left( 4 \alpha + \beta \right) - 5 C \\[4pt]
&=\frac12 s^2 \left( \frac\pi2 + 3\alpha \right)-5 \cdot \frac{1}{20}(2s)^2 \\[4pt]
&= \frac12 s^2 \left( \frac\pi2 + 3\operatorname{atan}\frac{1}{2} - 2 \right)
\end{align}$$
So, the target area, with $s = 2$, is

> $$2 \pi + 12 \operatorname{atan}\frac{1}{2} - 8 $$

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure how to find the area of the arc without using trigonometry though. BTW, what software do you use to draw such nice diagram?

Comment: @EdZeng: The answer *must* include an inverse-trig function *somewhere*, since, as you note, the angles involved are necessarily non-rational multiples of $\pi$. (For reference, this question addresses that issue directly: ["ArcTan(2) a rational multiple of $\pi$?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79861/arctan2-a-rational-multiple-of-pi).) If this is an "elementary school math question", then those kids must be pretty bright! :) (BTW: I use [GeoGebra](http://geogebra.org) for my diagrams.)

Answer (score 4):

This problem is so funny. @Robert Z's first answer of
$$4\sin^{-1}\left(\frac2{\sqrt5}\right)+8\sin^{-1}\left(\frac45\right)-8$$
was correct as is his latest answer of
$$4\left(\pi-2-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac2{11}\right)\right)$$
Integrating in polar coordinates I got
$$12\tan^{-1}\left(\frac12\right)-8+2\pi$$
Which was also correct. Taking the difference between sectors of circles and triangles, I get
$$16\sin^{-1}\left(\frac1{\sqrt5}\right)-8+4\sin^{-1}\left(\frac2{\sqrt5}\right)$$
Amazing that all $4$ of these expressions are the same! Even
$$8\pi-12\tan^{-1}2-8$$
As was seen in two nearly simultaneous answers was OK. How about sticking to Pythagorean triples with
$$6\sin^{-1}\left(\frac45\right)+2\pi-8$$

Comment: I found another equivalent answer (with no fractions) which is the similar to the one you obtained by polar coordinate.

Comment: @Robert Z I don't know why you deleted your post -- you had Michael Rozenberg beat by a couple of minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $ABCD$ be our square, where $B$ is a center of the circle with the radius $4$ and $AD$ is a diameter of the second circle.

Let these circles be intersected in points $A$ and $E$ and $G$ be the center of the second circle.

Thus, the needed area it's:
$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot4^2\cdot2\arctan\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot2^2\cdot2\arctan2-S_{ABEG}=$$
$$=16\arctan\frac{1}{2}+4\arctan2-4\cdot2=$$
$$=16\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan2\right)+4\arctan2-4\cdot2=8\pi-12\arctan2-8.$$