# Complex number to the power of n proof

Tags: complex-numbers

> Check if an $n \in \mathbb{Z_+}$ exists that satisfies:
>   $$(1+2i)^n = (1-2i)^n$$
>   Without using the unique prime factorization ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

I know that $(1-2i)^n = \overline{(1+2i)^n}$ so everything comes to prove that $(1+2i)^n \neq \overline{(1+2i)^n}$ for any $n \in \mathbb{Z_+}$

Let say $z = 1+2i$ then
I tried to write it as $z^n - \overline{z}^n = 4i(z^{n-1} + z^{n-2}*\overline{z} + z^{n-3}*\overline{z^2} + \cdots + z^2*\overline{z^{n-3}} + z*\overline{z^{n-2}}  + \overline{z^{n-1}})$

But this doesn't get me anywhere. Induction probably doesn't fit. The trigonometric form also doesn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think again when you say that the polar form doesn't help.

$1+2i$ has $r = \sqrt5$ and $\theta = \arctan 2$, so $(1+2i)^n$ has $r = \sqrt{5}^n$ and $\theta = (\arctan 2)n$.

$1-2i$ has $r = \sqrt5$ and $\theta = -\arctan 2$, so $(1+2i)^n$ has $r = \sqrt{5}^n$ and $\theta = -(\arctan 2)n$.

Since in both numbers $r$ is the same, then we just need $\theta$ to be the same. However, since by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79861/arctan2-a-rational-multiple-of-pi), $n \arctan 2$ does not divide $2\pi$ radians, the only integer possible is $n=0$.